# Testing ethereum events directly in solidity with truffle

Tags: unit-testing, events, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I found the following question for testing event logging in truffle using javascript:

[Test ethereum Event Logs with truffle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36627733/test-ethereum-event-logs-with-truffle)

But truffle also supports writing tests directly in solidity. However, I can't find any documentation for how to test event logging in solidity. Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: You could use Web3 into the test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*General remarks:*

Be aware that a smart contract can't access events. Events are by design just accessible from outside a smart contract. They are not directly stored in the blockchain. This means that you will not be able to test with pure solidity.

> The Log and its event data is not accessible from within contracts (not even from the contract that created them).
>   Source: https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.3/contracts.html#events

*Testing events with truffle works, just follow these steps:*

1) Create simple contract that emits events (*contracts/EventEmitter.sol*):

```
    pragma solidity 0.5.12;

    contract EventEmitter {

    // ---- EVENTS -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    event ConstructorDone(address owner, string message);
    event Counter(uint64 count);

    // ---- FIELDS -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    uint64 private _count = 0;
    string constant _message = '0x0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789';

    // ---- CONSTRUCTOR ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    constructor() public {
        emit ConstructorDone(msg.sender, _message);
    }

    // ---- STATISTICS FUNCTIONS ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    function getCount() public view returns (uint count) {
        return _count;
    }

    // ---- CORE FUNCTIONS ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    function increment() public {
        _count++;
        emit Counter(_count);
    }
}
```

2) Create test contract (*test/TestAnEventEmitter.sol*):

```
pragma solidity 0.5.12;

import "truffle/Assert.sol";
import "../contracts/EventEmitter.sol";

contract TestAnEventEmitter {

    EventEmitter private eventEmitter;

    uint eContracts = 0;

    address private owner;

    function assertCount() private {
        Assert.equal(eventEmitter.getCount(), eContracts, "Unexpected count of created contracts");
    }

    constructor() public{
        eventEmitter = new EventEmitter();
        owner = address(this);
    }

}
```

3) Create Test Code (*test/TestAnEventEmitter.js*):

```
const EventEmitter = artifacts.require("EventEmitter");
const truffleAssert = require('truffle-assertions');

/** Expected number of counter */
var eCount = 0;

/** The Contract's instance */
var eventEmitter;

global.CONTRACT_ADDRESS = '';

async function assertContractCount() {
    assert.equal(await eventEmitter.getCount.call(), eCount, "Wrong number of created contracts");
}

contract('EventEmitter', async () => {

    before(async () => {
        eventEmitter = await EventEmitter.new();
    });

    describe("1.1 Basic", function () {

        it("1.1.1 has been created", async () => {
            global.CONTRACT_ADDRESS = eventEmitter.address;
            console.log('        contract => ' + global.CONTRACT_ADDRESS);
            await assertContractCount();
        });

        it("1.1.2 should emit ConstructorDone event", async () => {
            // Get the hash of the deployment transaction
            let txHash = eventEmitter.transactionHash;

            // Get the transaction result using truffleAssert
            let result = await truffleAssert.createTransactionResult(eventEmitter, txHash);

            // Check event
            truffleAssert.eventEmitted(result, 'ConstructorDone', (ev) => {
                console.log('        owner => ' + ev.owner);
                return true;
            });
        });
    });

    describe("1.2 Check calls of increment()", function () {

        it("1.2.1 first call should increase the counts correctly", async () => {
            // Pre-Conditions
            await assertContractCount();

            // Creation
            let tx = await eventEmitter.increment();
            eCount++;

            // Expected Event
            truffleAssert.eventEmitted(tx, 'Counter', (ev) => {
                return parseInt(ev.count) === eCount;
            });

            // Post-Conditions
            await assertContractCount();
        });

        it("1.2.2 second call should increase the counts correctly", async () => {
            // Pre-Conditions
            await assertContractCount();

            // Creation
            let tx = await eventEmitter.increment();
            eCount++;

            // Expected Event
            truffleAssert.eventEmitted(tx, 'Counter', (ev) => {
                return parseInt(ev.count) === eCount;
            });

            // Post-Conditions
            await assertContractCount();
        });

        it("1.2.3 third call should increase the counts correctly", async () => {
            // Pre-Conditions
            await assertContractCount();

            // Creation
            let tx = await eventEmitter.increment();
            eCount++;

            // Expected Event
            truffleAssert.eventEmitted(tx, 'Counter', (ev) => {
                return parseInt(ev.count) === eCount;
            });

            // Post-Conditions
            await assertContractCount();
        });
    });
});
```

4) Run Tests:

```
$ truffle test
Using network 'development'.


Compiling your contracts...
===========================
> Compiling ./test/TestAnEventEmitter.sol



  Contract: EventEmitter
    1.1 Basic
        contract => 0xeD62E72c2d04Aa385ec764c743219a93ae49e796
      ✓ 1.1.1 has been created (56ms)
        owner => 0xbD004d9048C9b9e5C4B5109c68dd569A65c47CF9
      ✓ 1.1.2 should emit ConstructorDone event (63ms)
    1.2 Check calls of increment()
      ✓ 1.2.1 first call should increase the counts correctly (142ms)
      ✓ 1.2.2 second call should increase the counts correctly (160ms)
      ✓ 1.2.3 third call should increase the counts correctly (156ms)
```

Full sources (with package.json, etc.): 
https://github.com/MarkusSprunck/ethereum-event-scan

More about events and monitoring: 
https://www.sw-engineering-candies.com/blog-1/Ethereum-Event-Explorer-for-Smart-Contracts

(Disclaimer: I'm the author of this project and blog)

Answer (score 2):

Events are logs stored at blockchain. To get an event you need to watch the chain. 
http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/contracts.html#events

Solidity Truffle tests are contracts. And contracts just Ethereum accounts storing code. That code gets executed when that account receives a transaction.  Ethereum contracts can not watch chain to get an event logs. So Solidity does not support getting events. 
https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/White-Paper#ethereum-accounts

Answer (score 0):

Consider using OpenZeppelin Test Helper [expectEvent](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/test-helpers/0.5/api#expect-event).

Take for example event emitted during the construction:

*Contract*:

```cs
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.3;

contract Test {
    address public owner;

    event ContractCreated();

    constructor() {
        owner = msg.sender;

        emit ContractCreated();
    }
}
```

*truffle-test*:

```js
const { expectEvent } = require('@openzeppelin/test-helpers');

const TestContract = artifacts.require('Test');

contract('Test', function (accounts) {
    const [owner] = accounts;
    const txParams = { from: owner };

    beforeEach(async function () {
        this.testContract = await TestContract.new(txParams);
    });

    describe('construction', function () {
        it('initial state', async function () {
            expect(await this.testContract.owner()).to.equal(owner);

            await expectEvent.inConstruction(this.testContract, 'ContractCreated');
        });
    });
});
```

---

*package.json*

```json
{
..
  "devDependencies": {
    "@openzeppelin/test-helpers": "^0.5.10"
  }
..
}
```